# is it possible to get all point of pixel from line c# drawing 2d

Tags: c#, drawing, graphic

[image: c# line graphic]
I have a line C# code with drawing graphichpath, how to get all value every line pixel. not just point (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) point but I want all pixel from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an algorithm that should give you an estimation of the pixels between your two Points. Note it will not match what is on screen perfectly (which looks antialiased).

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>> EnumerateLineNoDiagonalSteps(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
    {
        int dx = Math.Abs(x1 - x0), sx = x0 < x1 ? 1 : -1;
        int dy = -Math.Abs(y1 - y0), sy = y0 < y1 ? 1 : -1;
        int err = dx + dy, e2;

        while(true)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(x0, y0);

            if (x0 == x1 && y0 == y1) break;

            e2 = 2 * err;

            // EITHER horizontal OR vertical step (but not both!)
            if (e2 > dy)
            {
                err += dy;
                x0 += sx;
            }
            else if (e2 < dx)
            { // <--- this "else" makes the difference
                err += dx;
                y0 += sy;
            }
        }
    }
```

Replace the Tuple with Point.

For more information, see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm
or
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm

Comment: The second link has been deleted (are you that xiaolin dude?)

Comment: Link fixed - it didn't like the single quote in the URL. And no - but I wish I had an algorithm named after me!